# Uncaught ReferenceError: TruffleContract is not defined 2

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript

Firstly, I have viewed ([Uncaught ReferenceError: TruffleContract is not defined](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60526/uncaught-referenceerror-trufflecontract-is-not-defined/60559#60559?newreg=cb34a3c9d0154cd6af24c3dfb0949ec0)) and am getting the same error for my smart contract:

[image]

However, I received this error while having the contract script defined in index.html:

```
<script src="js/truffle-contract.min.js"></script>
```

Additionally, I have tried adding the turffle contract through npm by adding `var contract = require("@truffle/contract");` to app.js and have bundled with `browserify` which results in an Unexpected identifier in app.js:

[image]

Both the solutions purposed in 2018 to this issue seem to have failed. Perhaps I am using `browserify` with App.js wrong? Or am missing something since the deprecation of `truffle-contract` to `@truffle/contract`?

App.js Code:

```
    App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},
  account: '0x0',
  loading: false,
  tokenPrice: 1000000000000000,
  tokensSold: 0,
  tokensAvailable: 750000,

  init: function() {
    console.log("App initialized...")
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function() {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      // If a web3 instance is already provided by Meta Mask.
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
      web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
    }
    return App.initContracts();
  },
  initContracts: function() {
    $.getJSON("NyankoCoinSale.json", function(nyankoCoinSale) {
      App.contracts.NyankoCoinSale = TruffleContract(nyankoCoinSale);
      App.contracts.NyankoCoinSale.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
      App.contracts.NyankoCoinSale.deployed().then(function(nyankoCoinSale) {
        console.log("Nyanko Coin Sale Address:", nyankoCoinSale.address);
      });
    }).done(function() {
      $.getJSON("NyankoCoin.json", function(nyankoCoin) {
        App.contracts.NyankoCoin = TruffleContract(nyankoCoin);
        App.contracts.NyankoCoin.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
        App.contracts.NyankoCoin.deployed().then(function(nyankoCoin) {
          console.log("Nyanko Coin Address:", nyankoCoin.address);
        });

        App.listenForEvents();
        return App.render();
      });
    })
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reading the docs on the @truffle/contract docs?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/contract

There are several steps to do before including the truffle-contract.min.js file in the index.html.